# LINQ to get average from grandchild

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to display some average values stored in database in a view using ViewModel. All goes well until I try to retrieve a value that is in a grandchild table.

The model looks like this: [Library model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QZ4B.jpg)

The ViewModel:

```
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfBooks { get; set; }
    public double AvgScore { get; set; }

    public double BookPeopleAvg { get; set; }
    public double AvidReadersAvg { get; set; }
    public double LibraryinternalAvg { get; set; }
```

And here is the controller action:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var authors = db.Authors               
            .Include(g => g.Books)
            .Include(g => g.Books.Select(c => c.Reviews))
            .Select(g => new AuthorViewModel
        {
            Firstname = g.Firstname,               
            NumberOfBooks = g.Books.Count(),
            AvgScore = g.Books.Average(c => (double?)c.Score) ?? 0,
            BookPeopleAvg = g.Books.Select(c => c.Reviews.Average(x => (double?)x.BookPeople) ?? 0)
        });
        return View(await authors.ToListAsync());
    }
```

I'm able to nicely get the AvgScore, but getting the average for BookPeopleAvg (and the other two) is proving difficult for me. I found some answers using GroupBy but I have been unable to weave them into my query.

The compiler error I'm getting for BookPeopleAvg is:

CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'double'

I have tried some different casts although I don't think the problem lies in the conversion despite the error message implying so.

Comment: A child's child is generally referred to as a "grandchild" or a "descendant"

Comment: @Jamiec A grandchild would be the correct term, descendant does not define level, though descendant does include grandchildren.

Comment: @Andrew I think that was my point. The specific term is a grandchild, which is encompassed by the general term descendant. I was perhaps a little unclear.

Comment: Thank you Jamiec and Andrew, always very helpful to know the correct terminology.

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, I understood what you meant and that you were technically correct, but for someone like OP who has referred to a grandchild as "child's child" specificity is important, so they understand the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
BookPeopleAvg = g.Books.Select(c => c.Reviews.Average(x => (double?)x.BookPeople) ?? 0)
```

to this

```
BookPeopleAvg = g.Books.SelectMany(c => c.Reviews).Average(x => (double?)x.BookPeople) ?? 0)
```

the way you did it you are actually selecting an IEnumerable of doubles (your averages)

Comment: This works wonderfully, thank you Liviu. I did have to remove the last closing parentheses, otherwise I got unbelievable amount of compiler errors.